# My app is still under review after they call me and explain me the changes should I make to my app

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I submit a new app to the iTunes connect, and it has been 15 days, and it's still reviewing. One of the apple technician called me few days ago and explain to me the changes should I make to my app so my app could be approved. And should they just reject my app after the call? Because it's still under reviewing for a very long time now. Should I do something about it like re submit the app to iTunes connect again or should I wait? By the way, I am submitting binary to test flight. And the test flight version is under reviewed.

Comment: If they don't reject your app, how do you submit a new binary with the changes they requested ? :D

Comment: @Zhang I think i can pull the binary myself. There is a option.

Comment: So you're saying Apple called you, told you to make some changes but still haven't rejected your app and continues to review the first version you submitted ?

Comment: @Zhang Yes. That's what I am talking about.

Comment: Why are you submitting to TestFlight ? If you want to test your app with users, there's the regular TestFlight which doesn't go through Apple: https://testflightapp.com/ Use that to test. If you think your app is ready for Appstore, you should submit to Appstore instead.

Comment: @Zhang Because if the test flight version is approved. Then the app is on the app store. I don't need to go through submit it to App Store again. And We have been using test flight all along. So, why not just submit it for review from there.